# How do I use git extensions to view an old version of an Excel file from it's history

Tags: excel, git, version, garbage, git-extensions

I'm trying to view/open an old version of an Excel file using git extension but can't seem to find an obvious way to achieve this!

So I viewed the "File History" as outlined in the docs:
https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_history.html#view

But I can only see garbage in the viewer due to this being an excel file as seen below.
[image]

I'd appreciate any advice on a straight forward was to view or open this old version of the Excel file from within git extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to download the old versions so that Excel itself can be used for review. Try right-clicking on any of the entries in the file history window and choosing "Save as".

This is what the menu looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was look for. I was searching the bottom half of the application thinking that the option should be there and didn't realise that there were other options in the context menus available from the top half where the versions of the file are listed.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gives a good solution to opening the file but doesn't explain the cause of the problem. What we think of as an Excel spreadsheet has been, in recent years, a .xlsx file, as you have pictured. This is more properly an "Office Open XML Workbook" and is really [just a ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats) with a variety of files inside. You can see one file mentioned in the image: [Content_Types].xml.

[ZIP files are compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) binary files and not human readable. In Git Extensions, the first line (just off screen in your question) correctly identifies it as a Binary file and then displays the file as if it were text, at least being nice enough to do it with a hex display. You would get a very similar experience opening your Excel file from in various hex editors.

Git Extensions is capable of displaying binary files at times. I know I've seen it display images. But they presumably need to implement custom support for each type of binary file, and as of 4.0.2 they still do not appear to have done so for Excel.

So you'll be unable to use Git Extensions to understand the contents of Excel* spreadsheets without opening them up with a third party tool (i.e. Excel). Opening the file up from disk, as suggested in the other answer, is your best solution.

*At least .xlsx spreadsheets. There are other formats, e.g. csv, that are not binary and would display much better in Git Extensions.